# Is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 compatible with SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, sql-server

Is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 compatible with SharePoint 2010? Does SharePoint Server needs any additional CU`s\SP`s to be installed to be in compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As a short answer:** Yes it's supported for SharePoint 2010, no need for SharePoint 2010  SP1.

**Note:**

- In order to use Microsoft SQL Server 2012, you must be running SharePoint Server 2010 SP1 or a later version of SharePoint Server 2010.
- SharePoint Server 2010 is not supported on Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

---

**Also, Check How Version support is determined by the equation in the following:**

> In order to maintain SharePoint and SQL Server compatibility we use
>   the “SharePoint N-1 on SQL Server N+1”  equation to determine version
>   support. Using SharePoint Server 2010 as an example, the N release of
>   SQL Server is 2008/2008 R2 and N+1 is SQL Server 2012. For Microsoft
>   SharePoint Server 2013 the N release of SQL Server is 2012 and the N+1
>   is SQL Server 2014.

For more details check [Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx)